# Code segfaults on 64bit works on 32bit

Tags: c, networking, segmentation-fault

The following code works on 32 bit debian, but results  in segfault on 64 bit. Adding code snippet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <signal.h>

void brk(int no){
   printf("^C Interrupt!\n");
   exit(1);
}

void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct hostent *host;                       /* init stuff */
    struct sockaddr_in sa;
    int net, error;
    int port=23, i, done=0;
    char *curr_ip, *del, *cm[100];
    int A1, A2, A3, A4;
    int B1, B2, B3, B4;
    int C1, C2, C3, C4;
   printf("\nDomain Scanner v2.0 by HoGs HeaD\nHit any key to end.\n");
   if(argc < 3){
        printf("Usage: domscan ip_begin ip_end port\n");
        exit(0);
   }

   signal(SIGINT, brk);
      if(argv[3]==NULL){
   }else{
      port=atoi(argv[3]);
   }

   /* Parse in the first Ip.... */

   curr_ip=argv[1];
   del=(char *)strtok(curr_ip, ".");
   A1=atoi(del);
   del=(char *)strtok(NULL, ".");
   A2=atoi(del);
   del=(char *)strtok(NULL, ".");
   A3=atoi(del);
   del=(char *)strtok(NULL, ".");
   A4=atoi(del);

   /* Read in Second Ip... */
   curr_ip = argv[2];
   del=(char *)strtok(curr_ip, ".");
   B1=atoi(del);
   del=(char *)strtok(NULL, ".");
   B2=atoi(del);
   del=(char *)strtok(NULL, ".");
   B3=atoi(del);
   del=(char *)strtok(NULL, ".");
   B4=atoi(del);

   /* We're finished parsing, now onto the actual scan... */
   C1=A1;
   C2=A2; /* SaVe DeM VaLueS! */
   C3=A3;
   C4=A4;
for(A4=C4;A4<=B4; A4++){
for(A3=C3;A3<=B3; A3++){
for(A2=C2;A2<=C2; A2++){
for(A1=C1;A1<=B1; A1++){
   sprintf(curr_ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", A1, A2, A3, A4);               /* build the ip */
   if( ( fork() ) == 0){                                          /* fork a child */
   sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
   sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(curr_ip);
   sa.sin_port = htons(port);                                     /* socket is set and... */
   net = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);                         /* create socket */
   if(net < 2){ 
      exit(2);     
   }
   alarm(5);                                                      /* wait 5 sec onds until we cancel connection */
   error = connect(net, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof sa);       /* attempt connection */

   error < 0 ? printf("Error connecting to: %s %s\n", curr_ip, strerror(errno)) : printf("Connection success at: %s\n", curr_ip);
   shutdown(net, 2);                                                /* disconnect socket */
   exit(0);                                                         /* exit child process */
   }

 }
}
}
}
  gets((char *)i);          /* Wait for enter to be pressed to exit */
}
```

This is a simple port scanner for scanning an ip range for a single port.

After compiling I also get the following warnings:

```
omscan.c: In function ‘brk’:
domscan.c:22:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
domscan.c: In function ‘main’:
domscan.c:38:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
domscan.c:50:8: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
domscan.c:52:8: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
domscan.c:54:8: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
domscan.c:56:8: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
domscan.c:61:8: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
domscan.c:63:8: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
domscan.c:65:8: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
domscan.c:67:8: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
domscan.c:86:7: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
domscan.c:93:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
domscan.c:100:8: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

Comment: So what do the warnings tell you and why do you expect the program to work correctly, although you get those warnings?

Comment: If a lot of road signs warns you that you are on dead end road, do you continue on that road.....?

Comment: `printf("^C Interrupt!\n");` is not async-signal-safe.  You should not call `printf()` in a signal handler.

Comment: OT: [brk](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html) is not a good name for a function, and don't use `gets()`

Comment: Those warnings you see are actually more like errors. BTW you should indent your code correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the headers that contain `exit`, `atoi`, `strtok` and `fork`:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

Most were evident from the warnings and error messages you posted.

When in doubt, always check the documentation to learn which header you need for a particular function. If you are unsure how to find the docs in your system, you can find documentation by googling `man <function>`.

You should also remove the cast of the return value from `strtok` as it masks the warning stemming from the missing declaration.

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>` also declares `atoi` which is used by the program. It should also have `#include <unistd.h>` to declare `fork`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks! I've added them to the answer. Those weren't obvious from the warnings list which is why I didn't pick them up.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the `strtok()` standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
>
> char *strtok(char *restrict s, const char *restrict sep);
> ```

Note well the

```
#include <string.h>
```

Your code does not include that header.

That means `strtok()` is assumed to return `int`, thus truncating the `char *` down from 64 to 32 bits, which then gets assigned to a `char *` - *as an improper pointer value*, thus causing the `SIGSEGV`.

Pay attention to compiler warnings.